# How to know the length of the array in assembly?

Tags: arrays, assembly, x86-16, masm

Here is a program that assumes that there is an array of characters starting from address zero relative to the data segment and whose members are (from left to right):

```
ABCDEVGTYO
```

The program checks if the elements of the array are different from each other. If so, it sets the value 0 in the DL register
and otherwise, it sets the value 1 in DL.

[image: The Question itself]

Can you help me solve that please?

I have tried to solve it but I don't know what to write on the second option (2).

Comment: Is there a chance that the final character in your sample above might actually be a binary zero? In DOS assembly (what this looks like), strings are typically terminated either with that, or a `$`.

Comment: its the letter 'O'

Comment: In assembly, as in C, you either: know it because you wrote the array definition, or because someone tells you (e.g. passing an array as a parameter, a length parameter might also be required and passed as parameter), or you measure it, e.g. by scanning for a terminator as we do with C-style strings, which are NUL-character (zero byte) terminated.  In Java or C#, unlike C and assembly, the object system remembers the size upon allocation so the array length can be had by an inquiry to the array object..

Comment: In this case you are given the string so you know the length.

Comment: (2) holds the max number of comparisons you can make (in the first iteration of the outer loop). It depends on the length of the array but is **not necessarily equal** to the length of the array!

Comment: With `assume cs:code ds:code` it seems strange that the task wants you to assume the array is at offset address zero where there is executable code already. An `assume cs:code ds:data` would have made so much more sense.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: You can't.

Computers at a low level don't really understand what arrays are, because they're not aware of where one piece of data ends. Considering your example:

```
myArray db "ABCDEVGTYO"
```

There are a variety of ways to write this, all of which are equivalent (although much harder to read). Here's a few examples of the same data written different ways.

```
myArray dw 4241h,4443h,5645h,5447h,594Fh
```

```
myArray db 41h,42h,43h,44h,45h,56h,47h,54h,4Fh,59h
```

No matter which of these you had used, the program would have run exactly the same, as the CPU cannot tell the difference.

But seeing as how you wrote the string to begin with, determining its length is trivial. I believe MASM allows you to use this syntax:

```
myArray db "ABCDEVGTYO"
myArrayEnd label byte

...

mov ax, MyArrayEnd-MyArray ;gives you the length as a constant
```